# I am creating a directive with datepicker and calling it in HTML, but it is telling datepicker is not a function

Tags: angularjs, html

```
app.directive("datepicker", function () {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
  }
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
  };
});

<input type = "text" datepicker class="form-control" ng-disabled = "x.status_flag == 1" ng-model = "x.closure_date" >
```

Here it is giving error that datepicker is not a function.

Comment: element.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }); 

this is not valid what are you trying to achive?

Comment: What's datepicker?, are you talking about jQueryUI widget?